# Gradle не видит проектной зависимости

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Есть следующая структура

```
MainProject
   settings.gradle
   build.gradle

   Proj1
       build.gradle
   Proj2
       build.gradle
```

В `MainProject/settings.gradle` я прописываю проекты

```
include 'Proj1', 'Proj2'
```

Для компиляции `Proj2` требуются классы из `Proj1`, поэтому в `Proj2/build.gradle` я пишу

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Proj1')

    //other dependencies
}
```

Когда делаю `gradle :Proj2:compileJava` у меня пишет, что пакет ( из `Proj1`) не найден, поэтому компиляция завершилась с ошибкой.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение.

Необходимо написать в `MainProject/build.gradle` следующее

```
project(':Proj2') {
    dependencies {
       compile project(':Proj1');
    }
}
```

и файлик `Proj2/build.gradle` необходимо удалить.

Соответственно встал вопрос - почему не работает так, как я написал в вопросе, но это уже другой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570467/gradle-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Comment: Как мы выяснили в связанном вопросе, это на самом деле не решение.