# Gradle модульные зависимости

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Есть следующая структура

```
MainProject
   settings.gradle
   build.gradle

   Proj1
       build.gradle
   Proj2
       build.gradle
```

В `MainProject/settings.gradle` я прописываю проекты

```
include 'Proj1', 'Proj2'
```

`Proj2` зависит от `Proj1`.

Если я пишу в `Proj2/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Proj1');
}
```

то градл не видит классов из `Proj`. Если же тоже самое я опишу в `MainProject/build.gradle`

```
project(':Proj2') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':Proj1')
    }
}
```

То все скомпилируется верно (из учета, что файлика `Proj2/gradle.build` не будет).

Почему 1 вариант не работает? Это же лучше в том плане, что вся логика будет содержаться в своем файлике `build.gradle`, а не в одном общем.

**P.S. Update**

В комментариях попросили сделать минимальный гитовый [проект](https://github.com/AndrewBystrov/TempGradle).

Если прямо так склонировать и запустить `gradle compileJava` из корня, то все будет скомпилировано.

Если сделать следующее :

1. В корневом `build.gradle` закоментировать c 5 по 10 строки `project(':Proj2') {...}`
2. Переименовать `Proj2/b2uild.gradle2` в `Proj2/build.gradle` и запустить `gradle compileJava` - то возникнет описанная выше ошибка.

my@ubuntu:~/Projects/TempGradle$ gradle -version

---

### Gradle 3.0

Build time:   2016-08-15 13:15:01 UTC

Revision:     ad76ba00f59ecb287bd3c037bd25fc3df13ca558

Groovy:       2.4.7

Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015

JVM:          1.8.0_102 (Oracle Corporation 25.102-b14)

OS:           Linux 3.13.0-96-generic amd64

Comment: У меня первый вариант работает нормально. Покажите, какими именно командами вы запускаете сборку в обоих вариантах. И если можно, сделайте минимальный проект на github, демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Comment: я пользуюсь gradle compileJava из MainProject. А градл какой версии у вас? У меня 3.0. По поводу проекта на гитхабе - немного попозже сделаю.

Comment: У меня gradle 2.14, но я не думаю, что это влияет.

Comment: @Roman обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проект не собирается из-за того, что `Proj2/build.gradle` отличается от блока `project(':Proj2') { ... }` корневого проекта. В `Proj2/build.gradle` есть секция

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir('src')
        }
    }
}
```

которой нет в `MainProject/build.gradle`. Из-за неё (точнее, см. далее) и возникает ошибка. Без этой секции у вас не вызывается компиляция java-исходников из `Proj2/src/` (по умолчанию gradle ищет java-исходники в `Proj2/src/main/java/`, см. [Java project layout](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout)).

Из-за неправильного расположения исходников Proj1 и Proj2 фактически являются пустыми проектами, поэтому и не возникает ошибок компиляции. После добавления вышеупомянутой секции Proj2 становится не пустым и возникает ошибка компиляции, т.к. Proj1 всё ещё пустой.

Чтобы исправить, переместите исходники в правильное место и уберите `sourceSets { ... }` из `Proj2/build.gradle`. Если исходники по какой-то причине переместить нельзя, то сконфигурируйте `sourceSets` для всех проектов.

Comment: Получается, если я пропишу sourceSets для всех проектов, то я смогу объявлять в Proj2 депенденси и тому подобное?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за разъяснение.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Да, зависимости можно объявлять в `Proj2/build.gradle`.